# How to send a DM from a looped event in Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, bots, discord.py

Trying to send a PM to a user but nothing is working:

```
async def main_loop():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    while not bot.is_closed():
        # do stuff...
        if some_random_condition:
            user = bot.get_user(user_id)
            user.send_message("some message")  # doesn't work, user is Nonetype, id is correct though

bot.loop.create_task(main_loop())
bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Since this is just a looped function I don't really have a context or message object passed in through discord.py's framework, I just have the bot - but I don't know how to use the bot to get access to the user to send them a PM.

Comment: You’re gonna have to be more precise, saying “nothing is working” it’s too vague

Comment: The comment I have in there says "user is Nonetype", by this I mean that `bot.get_user(user_id)` returns None and so when I do user.send_message, it errors out because it's None.

Comment: Did you enable intents.members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're getting the correct ID based on your comment, this is what you would have to do:

```py
async def main_loop():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    while not bot.is_closed():
        # do stuff...
        if some_random_condition:
            user = await bot.fetch_user(user_id)
            await user.send("some message")

bot.loop.create_task(main_loop())
bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Comment: This was it - I had the wrong function names I guess! Thanks